# mod_rewrites .htaccess not working with godaddy hosting (linux)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my site `www.sqcp.com` in testing on another linux server, all worked as it should. However since moving it to godaddy, the mod_rewrites haven't been working, therefore none of the other pages have been accessible. Even if I create a blank directory/folder in the what it's trying to tidy the url to it then works for that page (obviously isn't a fix).

So any help would be great here my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule (.*)/{2,}$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ $1?s=$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*/)?staff.php/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+) $1staff.php?s=$2 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapping. If it's disabled, you *do want* the according server error to show up. It's not easy for anyone to help you with a block of RewriteRules without knowing the actual directory structure or intent. Needs more explaining what is working and what is not. You might also need to beg GoDaddy support to enable the `RewriteLog` for you, when you can't debug it otherwise.

Comment: Shall I remove the whole top line ? The directory is very simple with all the pages just in the root along with the .htaccess file. The home page works fine and also vacancies page works as there is a folder in the root called vacancies (which doesnt actually contain the page itself)

Comment: `godaddy support have been useless`? Strange! =) Anyway, try what mario suggests: remove `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` **and** `<\IfModule>`

Comment: Ok i have made the change no difference. I have an error logs folder and an Apache log folder will these be of any use ?

Comment: Do yo have `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in your `.conf` file?

Comment: where will I find my .conf file ? godaddy are saying mod_rewrite is enabled at global levl so i didnt need to enable it in my .conf file

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey, GoDaddy run a bog standard SHS provider template: mod_rewrite is loaded; rewrite logging is *always* disabled.  PHP initiated on a per-request basis to enforce per UID access control.  [Here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-32) is a description of my SHS profile if you want more details.

Comment: when i change the .htaccess contents to whats here [link]http://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy[link] the buttons now all work (apart from vacancies) as there is a directory called that but they obviously all direct to index.php / homepage

Comment: Or do I just change host? as this is becoming a big pain! can anyone recommend a cheap one that supports multiple domains and this .htaccess file would work on like it did on the web devs server

Comment: Also just checked to see if the website was still up on the dev server and it is and works 100% fine on there [link] http://sqcp.website.stage.lemonskip.co.uk/ compared to http://www.sqcp.com on godaddy

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy run a perfectly good shared hosting service, addressing a large market sector -- users who want an active site (that is with some scripting) but without the cost or complexity of paying for or having the expertise to administer their own Linux VM. This isn't a GoDaddy problem.  Its yours.

So first get to understand the environment that you are running under by running a `phpinfo` script, and make sure it creates the variables that you use.  As far as I can see on your example:

Rules 1-3 are 301 redirections to enforce some request naming convention.

- Rule 1 redirects  `/index.php` to `/`
- Rule 2 collapses trailing multiple `/` to a single `/`
- Rule 3 rewrites GET requests for `*.php` to `*.php/`

Rules 4-6 map public URIs to internal ones

- Rule 4 rewrites `/*/yyyy-mm-dd-word` to `*?s=yyyy-mm-dd-word` (note no QSA)
- Rule 5 seems to be attempting to rewrite `/*/staff.php/word` to `/*/staff.php?s=word` but the syntax is wrong for this.
- Rule 6 replaces any trailing `/` by `.php` on redirection
- Rule 7 strips any trailing '/' unless the uri is a directory with an index.php (I assume that you are assuming a `DirectoryIndex index.php` (is this the case for GoDaddy?)

This is all hopelessly confused.  Are you hiding or exposing the `.php` extension? Because Rule 3,5 and 6 are inconsistent.  And rule 5 would seem more logical as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/staff.php/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+) $1/staff.php?s=$2 [L]
```

Go back to the drawing board and work out what you are trying to do with your htaccess rules; what you want your public URI grammar to be; how your scripts are laid out; what redirects you want to pass back to the client browser and which you want Apache to handle as internal rewrites and what extra conditions are needed to prevent looping and misfiring.  Make sure this makes sense and then debug them by building up your `.htaccess` file one rule at a time and using test requests to exercise each rule in turn to validate what its doing.

Comment: I wish I had the ability to re-write it from scratch but the reason why I was asking on here anyway was for help as that was just given to us by a web dev company we used I'm merely a network engineer with no developing experience

Comment: I wouldn't use "merely"; just a different speciality.  Whoever decided to rehost the app to GoDaddy should have realised that this might have a regression impact on the apps and app-support is need here.  If you start changing something you don't understand, you could just dig yourself a deeper hole :-(

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding the following at the start of your htaccess file. I had the same problem getting rewrites to work on GoDaddy which worked everywhere else:

```
Options -Multiviews
```